# What happens if Array index is 'X'

Tags: verilog

I have a question on what's the expected behavior when an array index is 'X'.

For example:

`assign c = a[b];`

where b is 1'b, but is 'X' in the entire simulation.

'a' holds 2 elements, a[0] and a[1], and a[0] = 0, a[1] = 0 for the entire simulation.

I originally expected 'c' (a[b]) to be 'X' since b is 'X', but simulation showed that c = 0. What's the reason behind this?

Thanks

Comment: There is no X in hardware, only 0s and 1s. You gave a 'don't care' input to simulator, simulator doesn't care as well and gave you a value 0/1 of its choice which it thinks as optimal. So why should you care what it gives?

Comment: @MituRaj The simulator doesn't pick a value of its choice - there are defined rules about how they propage. `x` should lead to more `x` unless the logic dicates otherwise. It can be useful to know that for example an `x` value doesn't propagate somewhere which should always have a defined value - for example if `requestLaunch = x` but `approveLaunch = 0`, you wouldn't want to see `launchMissile = x`, because then something is wrong in your logic. Equally you wouldn't want the sim to pick any value or a random 0, because then you wouldn't be able to pick up on a potentially disaterous mistake.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter  Not necessary always. For eg: inside SV case statement, you can drive a signal to X and then synthesiser can substitute the X with 0/1 depending which is optimal for implementation. This can be simulated in post-synthesis simulation as 0/1 and it will progagate downstream as 0/1. Not Xs.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior on any simulator; `c` is always x.  Show all your signal declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all entries in `a` are always zero then the simulator can work out that regardless of the value of `b`, `c` will always be zero. It will then optimise it away to just

```
assign c = 0;
```

Hence `b` being `x` makes no difference to the result.

If you were to set one of the value in `a` to something different, or possibly adding logic to allow it to be set to something else, then you will probably get `c` being `x`.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly, say if 'a' contains 3 elements, with a[2] always being X, then in that case 'c' (a[b]) would be X right?